# Not able to change app icon after adding elegant button and getting this error

Tags: android, gradle

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon
>   value=(@drawable/bagi) from AndroidManifest.xml:10:9-38   is also
>   present at [com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-43 value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher).  Suggestion:
>   add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to  element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-35:19 to override.

Comment: the question itself give suggestion !!!! read the logs properly

Answer (score 0):

As it says `tools:replace="android:icon"` does the trick for me

Comment: Where to add this line?

Comment: At your manifest inside "<application", before android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"